Elementor header and footer builder not loading
why my Elementor header and footer builder not loading ?
i try all solution like deactivite all piugins except elementor and elementor header and footer plugins and check and also reinstall latest version of wrodpress but still elementor header and footer not loading

I was also having this issue for a while, I did the following to make it work again:

Go to Settings > Permalinks and click on "Save Changes" to re-generate the permalinks.
Go to Appearance > Elementor Header and Footer Builder then click on the "Edit with Elementor"

It works again !!!

Draft the header or footer and try opening it from the Elementor builder

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can turn on safe mode in elementor. So work starts.


Brother, I enable the safe mode in Elementor(tool) and then go to Appearance>>Elementor header & footer>>Footer page(edit with Elementor) when I click it directs me to my post pages instead of opening the footer section, then I disable safe mode in Elementor(tool) and again open Appearance>>Elementor header & footer>>Footer page(edit with Elementor) and it works. Thank U Brother

Just click the page settings >> General Settings >> Page Layout from Elementor canvas to Elementor Full width. It solve my problem

im using elementor header and footer plugin UAE in which header is visible on website but footer is not visible with the same setting

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
